# Linux / Xen Server freezes

Tags: linux, xen

An Ubuntu LTS server runs xen with dom0 and one virtual machine. The server is freezing permanently on a number of seemingly unrelated operations, such as:

- Creation of a new file system with mkfs.ext3 on a LVM device. (this is consistent).
- Restart of xend via /etc/init.d/xend restart
- apt-get dist-upgrade on configuration phase of some fairly innocent stuff.

Also, yesterday I noticed that virtualized imagine had lost time synch and complained about backwards clock in dmesg.

Unfortunately, I don't have the screen shots on what happens actually on the console of the server (it is co-located).

I want to blame ram, but do You have other suggestions?

UPDATE: After further investigation, it appears that all those actions only kill network. When I visited the server in data center and logged onto console, I wasn't able to reach my router/gateway. How bizare.

Comment: Is there any useful information in dmesg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the network issue, xen works better if you don't let it set up the bridge...

for /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto xen-br0
iface xen-br0 inet static
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        address 10.2.2.2
        gateway 10.2.2.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp:

```
(vif-script vif-bridge bridge=xen-br0)
```

this way starting and stopping xen won't mess with your network interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I'd be running a lengthy memtest first up, but there's a decent possibility it's something else hardwareish -- run a complete burnin of all system components, and monitor all your temperatures.

The clock thing is unrelated, Xen just can't keep good time.  NTP forever.

Comment: What would You reccommend for complete burning?

Comment: We use breakin from http://www.advancedclustering.com/view-document-details/23-bootimage-includes-breakin-v3.0-for-x86_64-kernel-and-initrd-only.html and it works pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

That does look like hardware failure. Test the ram and also check the hdd for bad sectors. Also check the log files for any warnings.

Comment: Logs are always clean :(

Comment: And the system completely freezes? I still recommend checking for bad ram and bad hdd sectors. If it's possible, run something like Prime95. When it's a CPU or RAM problem, it will show. Also, what are the temps?